# How can I sort this Array in Swift 3 ? ( Picker View ) ( Core Data )

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift3, uipickerview

[image]

[image]

How can I sort this Array in my PickerView ? I am using Swift 3.

Comment: You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sorting array every time in `titleForRow` you need to sort it once after you initialized your `stores` array.

```
stores.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
```

Now `stores` array is sorted by name property now simply return the name from `titleForRow` method.

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return stores.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return stores[row].name
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(stores[row].name)
}
```

Comment: @YuOn If edited answer is also not work then you need to add you need to show more code also don't add image of code add the code in question

Comment: can i use this method? but i do not know how to use this methods.  stores.sort(by:      -> Bool)

Comment: where should i put the ( sortedStores = stores.sorted { $0.name < $1.name } )

Comment: @YuOn After you initialized your stores array, if you still don't get edit your question with actual code instead of image with code

Comment: ok i got it . I am trying to solve this problem with your advice.

Comment: ermmm .. still can't.

Comment: do you have Discord account or how can I DM you easily ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139928/discussion-between-nirav-d-and-yu-on).

Comment: It helps !! Great answer !

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.1:

```
var arr = ["aaa","zz","ddd","mnm","zzzz"]
var newArr = arr.sorted()
print(newArr)
//log: ["aaa", "ddd", "mnm", "zz", "zzzz"]
```